# Flex: Multiple TextInput focus issue

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

The issue that I've been confronted with for some time now is that a `TextInput` never loses focus.

I tried to solve this issue by putting `stage.focus=null` on the click event of the `Application`. However, this prevents the `TextInput` from ever getting the focus. This can be solved by having `stopPropagation` on the `TextInput`. This may be a solution.

What I want to achieve is to have the `TextInput` lose focus on click outside, on another `TextInput` or any other element.

Can you recommend another way to do it?

Comment: You can try focusEnabled for text input.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
textInput.addEventListener(FlexMouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN_OUTSIDE, forceFocusOut);

private function forceFocusOut(e:Event):void{
   stage.focus = null;
}
```

Comment: this is not triggered when I click outside the `TextInput`